# how to avoid writing a gross for-loop on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

```
import pandas as pd

begin_month = pd.Series([1, 19, 45, 32, 54])
end_month = pd.Series([19,45,32,54,99])

inventory = pd.DataFrame({"begin_month":begin_month, "end_month": end_month})
```

I want to make a third column, a boolean value, that says, "for each month, does the begin_month inventory == the previous month's end_month inventory level?"

I can write a foul for-loop that does this, but am wondering how I could write a vectorized action to achieve the same thing.  Furthermore, the edge case is index location 0, for which there is nothing to compare its begin_month value to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

begin_month = pd.Series([1, 19, 145, 32, 54])
end_month = pd.Series([19,45,32,54,99])

df = pd.DataFrame({"begin_month":begin_month, "end_month": end_month})

df['parity'] = df['begin_month'] == df['end_month'].shift()
df.ix[0,'parity'] = True

print df
```

The key is to use .shift() so that you can compare the current row with an adjacent row.   and I set df.ix[0, 'parity'] = True because it has no predecessor to compare it to.

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Haris I added explanation in case the answer was not self-explanatory.